# making a wave periodic on matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, matlab-figure

how we can make a wave periodic(which already have the waveform)?

Comment: Is the wave form defined by a function or do you have some sample of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate the samples you have to create periods of the signal using the function [`repmat()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html).

Comment: I found my answer

https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/109112-periodic-function-with-n-cycles

Comment: You should post the answer here and mark the question as answered.